# solution for system of non homo linear recurrence relations

Tags: recurrence-relations, functional-equations

After finishing some BP(back propagation) problem, I ended up by these equations:
$$W_1(0) = 1.5$$$$W_2(0) =0$$
$$W_1(x+1) = W_1(x) -2B(x)+\frac{W_2(x)-W_1(x)-1}{5}$$
$$W_2(x+1) = W_2(x) -2B(x) +\frac{W_1(x)-W_2(x)+1}{5}$$
where $$B(odd) = -0.1$$ and $$B(even) = 0.1$$
I want a closed formula for $W_1(x)$ and $W_2(x)$, and
I googled to find a way to approach, but I didn't find any solution.

Could someone give me a way to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write it as

$$v(x+1) = v(x) -2b(x)+c(w(x)-v(x)-1)$$
$$w(x+1) = w(x) -2b(x) +c(v(x)-w(x)+1)$$

$c = \frac15$.

Subtracting,

$v(x+1)-w(x+1)
=v(x)-w(x)+c(2w(x)-2v(x)-2)\\
=(v(x)-w(x))(1-2c)-2c
$

Let $u(x)=v(x)-w(x)
$. Then
$u(x+1)=du(x)-2c$
where
$d=1-2c
$.

From this, we can get $u(x)$.

Adding,

$v(x+1)+w(x+1)
=v(x)+w(x)-4b(x)
$.

Let $t(x)=v(x)+w(x)$.
Then
$t(x+1)=t(x)-4b(x)
$.

From  this
we can easily get
$t(x)
$.

Then
$v(x)=(t(x)+u(x))/2,
w(x)=(t(x)-u(x))/2
$.